# How to decode this METAR published during huricane Harvey?

Tags: metar

I have the following METAR from the FAA Aviation Weather Center (AWC) website for KCRP (Corpus Christi Airport):

```
 KCRP 260551Z AUTO A2935 RMK AO2 SLPNO 6//// 402610239 53014 PWINO
```

A few questions:

1. How do we know what the altimeter setting is if the sea level pressure indicator is inoperative?
2. What does 6//// mean?
3. What does 402610239 53014 mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest changing the title, else this question is of relatively limited interest: the [METAR message for KNGP](http://en.allmetsat.com/metar-taf/southern-texas.php?icao=KNGP) has been already updated with new values.

---

How to set the altimeter when the "sea level pressure" information is not available?

- ATC will be able to provide the information. When aerodrome QNH is not available, the Regional Pressure Setting is used ("safe" setting for the highest location of the region).

`6////`: Group `6RRRR`, 3- and 6-hour precipitation amounts

- 3- and 6-hour precipitation amounts are missing, sensor not operative or not reachable.

`402610239`: Group `4snTTTsnTTT`, 24-hour max/min temperature in tenths degrees

- Maximum temperature in the past 24 hours + 26.1 °C.
- Minimum temperature in the past 24 hours + 23.9 °C.

`53014`: Group `5appp`, hourly pressure tendency and and actual change in tenths hPa

- Atmospheric pressure now higher than 3 hours ago. Decreasing or steady, then increasing; or increasing then increasing more rapidly.
- Variation is 1.4 hPa

`PWINO`: Sensor status indicators (`RVRNO`, `PWINO`, `PNO`, `FZRANO`, `TSNO`, `VISNO_LOC`, `CHINO_LOC`)

- Precipitation identifier information (rain or snow) not available.

See [this decoder](http://www.flightutilities.com/MRonline.aspx) and [this list](https://www.unc.edu/~haines/metar.html) of METAR abbreviations.